# checking format without using function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, validation, postgresql-9.5

How to check date values is expected format or not I need to check date values is yyyy-mm-dd format or not if not then display status 0 
dob and doj have datatype varchar

I need to implement this logic without using user defined functions in postgresql

Table: Emp

```
Table: Emp

eid | ename | dob        | doj
1   | abc   | 1900-01-19 | 2019-02-20
2   | dx    | 1900-29-02 | 2019-04-22
3   | xy    | 1989-10-26 | 2018-27-02
4   |ji     | 2000-23-01 | 2019-29-04
5   |jj     |1980/04/09  |1999/08/20
```

based on above data i want check date format should be yyyy-mm-dd if not flag will show like below:

```
eid | dobdateformatstatus | dojdateformatstatus
1   | 1                   | 1
2   | 0                   | 1
3   | 1                   | 0
4   | 0                   | 0
5   |0                    |0
```

I got soluton for existing question and query is :

```
create function try_cast_to_date(p_in text)
returns date 
as $$
begin
    begin
        return $1::date;
    exception 
        when others then return null;
    end;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
then use it in query:

select 
    eid, 
    ename, 
    (try_cast_to_date(dob) is not null) dobdateformatstatus, 
    (try_cast_to_date(doj) is not null) dojdateformatstatus  
from mytable
```

can you please tell me how to write query to achieve this task without using user-defined functions in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't have a work-around, so your solution is probably the best.  That said, the real best is to store dates as `date`s.  Then you can handle inadequacies on input rather than storing bad data.

Comment: This is another great example on why storing date values in `varchar` column is a  bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well the user defined function is the clearest, if not the most correct solution. However, without a user defined function it you can do this with a regular expression. The following offers the most general regexp for validation dates, however it does incorrectly flag 29-Feb as invalid on leap years (validating that with regexp begins to get complicated) but otherwise does validate dates. That regexp:

```
'^(0[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3})-((0[13578]|10|12)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|02-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))$')
```

It breaks down as follows:

- ^  ==> Starting at beginning of string.
- (0[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3}) ==> year in range 0001 - 9999
  (Postgres can actually support years far beyond that but it should be
  sufficient).
- -  ==> literal character
- (0[13578]|10|12) ==> For months Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec

  - - ==> literal
  - (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) ==> day is in range 01 to 31
- 02 For Feb
- - ==> literal
- (0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]) ==> day is in range 01 to 28
- (0[469]|11) ==> For Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov

  - - ==> literal
  - (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30) ==> day is in range 01 to 30
- $ ==> end of string

The following test each day for 2020, and a few valid and invalid dates tossed in:

```
with date_validator(pattrn) as
     ( select '^(0[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3})-((0[13578]|10|12)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|02-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))$')
   , extras (dt) as 
       (select * from ( values  ('2020/02/15'), ('abcd'),('00-01-01'),('1215-06-15'),('1776-07-04'),('bad_date')) as t(dt))  
   , test_data as 
     (select ('2020-01-01'::timestamp + lev * interval '1 day')::date::text dt
          from generate_series(0,365) lev   
        union all 
        select * from extras
       ) 
select dt, dt ~ pattrn "Is Valid Date"
  from test_data 
  cross join date_validator;
```

And finally with your test data and returning 1 for valid dates and 0 for invalid:

```
with  emp(eid,ename,dob,doj) as 
      ( values (1, 'abc', '1900-01-19', '2019-02-20' )
             , (2, 'dx',  '1900-29-02', '2019-04-22' )
             , (3, 'xy',  '1989-10-26', '2018-27-02' )
             , (4, 'ji',  '2000-23-01', '2019-29-04' )
             , (5, 'jj',  '1980/04/09', '1999/08/20' )
      )
   , date_validator(pattrn) as
     ( select '^(0[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3})-((0[13578]|10|12)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|02-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))$')
select eid
     , case when dob ~ pattrn::text then 1 else 0 end "dob date format status"
     , case when doj ~ pattrn::text then 1 else 0 end "doj date format status"
  from emp cross join date_validator ;
```

Of course if I had to implement this I would certainly hide it away is a user defined function. I certainly would not trust trying to type it each time. But as others have pointed out **store your dates as date** (or timestamp) and you will not have this issue.

Comment: if i compare date with time that time above query is not woking.its woking only datesvalue.can you please tell me how to validate date with time also.

Comment: That could be work that out, but your question is strictly about date in a particular format which I answered. If you need date and time post another question. You can indicate its a followup and link to this one. Make sure you indicate the exact format you need. If this solved your initial issue please accept.